# Nextjs14, redirect and revalidatePath in server action

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm a bit confused about when to use both revalidatePath and redirect in combination.

Some actions seem to require redirection while others don't. Is there any criteria that can help me determine when to use both or just stick with revalidatePath?

Since I have written some server actions, if I don't use the redirect after revalidating the path, the page will still display outdated data.